# Why do i get Exception User-unhandled System.Data.sqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '400,000' to datatype int.'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am developing a business app using ASP.NET and C#, when I input data and click the save button, it throws that error:

> Exception User-unhandled
>
> System.Data.sqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '400,000' to datatype int.'

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SMS.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CoursePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Student_Management_System.CoursePage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <h1>Course Page</h1>

    <div style ="background-color:aqua; width: 292px; margin-left: 0px;">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Course Name:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtCourseName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Course Fee:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtCourseFee" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Course Duration:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="-- SELECT --" Value="select" 
Selected="True"></asp:ListItem> 
                            <asp:ListItem Text="3 Months" Value="3 Months"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="6 Months" Value="6 Months"></asp:ListItem> 
                            <asp:ListItem Text="9 Months" Value="9 Months"></asp:ListItem> 
                            <asp:ListItem Text="1 Year" Value="1 Year"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="2 Years" Value="2 Years"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="ButCourse" runat="server" Text="Save" 
OnClick="ButCourse_Click" /></td>
            <td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Student_Management_System
{
    public partial class CoursePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void ButCourse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myconnection"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);

            string sqlquery = "Insert into [dbo].[Course] (CourseName, CourseFee, CourseDuration) values (@CourseName, @CourseFee, @CourseDuration)";

            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);

            sqlconn.Open();

            sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseName", TxtCourseName.Text);
            sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseFee", TxtCourseFee.Text);
            sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseDuration", DropDownList1.Text);

            sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Response.Write("<script>alert('Course Added Successfully.!!');</script>");

            TxtCourseName.Text = "";
            TxtCourseFee.Text = "";

            sqlconn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Because `400,000` is a locale-specific string. In some locales it means four hundred thousand, in others it means four hundred point zero zero zero.

Comment: If you define the data type of your parameter in your code, using `Parameters.Add` instead, then it *may* be able to implicitly cast the value to a `int` based on the culture of the local device. Better yet, however, seeing as the value should not contain any characters other that digits, don't allow them; force the user to enter `400000` or `400` (which ever is correct).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i tried using digits without character and it worked